# Automatic merging of duplicate cells in google docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a sorted section of my spreadsheet and am trying to take it from

```
Name1 C32 5000
Name1 C28 2500
Name1 C72 900
Name2 C540 500
Name2 C320 900
Name3 C28 2500
Name3 C32 900
```

to

```
Name1 C32 5000
      C28 2500
      C72 900
Name2 C540 500
      C320 900
Name3 C28 2500
      C32 900
```

The area is always changing in size depending on what product the names have and the quantity they have. As well as how many names there are. The ideal solution would be for the extra duplicate names to be erased for viewing purposes automatically.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIF` function with relative referencing of cells to achieve this. The following formula will populate the first occurrence of the `Name` column only

```
=if(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)=1,A1,"")
```

[Here is a working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11-dFp2xmI-h12pWNQgUgtHF55Q5bBeBsYlLOH7955nI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks! That worked out. Though it caused another problem I did not think about. I'm using SUMIFS to count the original input data, and it relies on the name being in the first cell to count everything up attached to that name. Though after implementing this it now counts "0" since the name is now blank.

I probably should have thought that out earlier, and am a bit stumped on how to work around that. Unless there is a way to hide the cells contents, but the information still exists.

Comment: Well that's easy. You could have two columns and hide one of them.